# Android test automation on multiple emulator devices

Tags: android

I have recently started Android test automation. I have used Robotium to develop my test scripts. I run the scripts on Android emulators using Genymotion. I want to run my test suite on multiple emulators at same time, can anyone please help me with how to do it?

Comment: They should already run on all available devices - don't they?

Comment: You can use spoon to run multiple devices as well as get good test report.

https://github.com/square/spoon

Comment: Any good tutorial to follow for this?

Comment: If you have a Raspberry-Pi, you can also use that instead of the emulator. The performance is much better: http://innovation.avg.com/2016/06/15/raspberry-pi-for-android-test-automation/